# What could this device be?

Tags: device

I was visiting a hotel and by accident found there is somekind of device under the sink.

It consisted of 2 parts that were connected wires.

[image]
[image]

I think it measures something, maybe temperature or similar. Any suggestions?

---

[image]

Comment: an led strip...

Comment: Why not ask the hotel manager?

Comment: "it can do anything, it could be hero"

Comment: It's a lowish grade LED strip light. Designed to run at 12V nominal. Each section has 3 LEDs in series plus a resistor. Here R = 151 = 150 Ohms. If LEDS are nominal 3V each ILED = (12 - (3 x 3V))/15- = 3/150 = 20 mA which is typical LEd max If. At 15V VLED will rise to maybe 3.3V so I = (15 - 3.3x3)/150 ~~= 33 mA. \ In [your large photo](http://i.stack.imgur.com/dn7Ng.jpg) L19 20 21 and R7 at rh end are clear and show things well. When posting pictures like this and you have a nice large original image then showing a crop of the sharp detail as at rh end helps heaps.

Comment: See crop of your photo above

Answer (score 3):

The white box is just a casing for some circuitry inside (probably a battery or some power supply).

The strip looks to be just an LED strip, it's purpose I have no idea but I imagine it is useful to someone. Ask management in the hotel if it is concerning you.

It might be something useful to maintenance - lighting up the underside of the sink to they can carry out repairs without having to hold a flashlight, but that is purely speculation so don't go with it.

Comment: Maintenance? Whenever you need it, the batteries would be dead... I guess they took this room to make nice photos for their website/catalog and wanted to pimp them with some light from below the sink. May be, a look at their website will show it.

Comment: @sweber Maybe there is a switch inside the plastic box that we cannot see! Yes that too could be the case.